# Facebook Prophet saturation failling

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet

I´m using Prophet to predict sales and using the saturation parameter to not have negative values:

df_prof = df_prof.sample(1000)
df_prof['cap'] = 6000
df_prof['floor'] = 10

m = Prophet(growth='logistic')

```
m.fit(df_prof)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
future['cap'] = 6000
future['floor'] = 10
forecast = m.predict(future)
fig1 = m.plot(forecast)

fig2 = m.plot_components(forecast)
```

But the predicted values have values outside both thresholds, lower and higher

[image]

Comment: can you post working minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

it's because the forecasting method is not set to logistic.